# Ruby string.scan(/#{regexp_pattern}/) - execution time

Tags: ruby, regex

Problem:

ruby .scan with regex pattern taking up to 5 minutes. Time depends on string that are scanning.

Tests run on ruby '2.5.1', and ruby '2.4.2'.

Examples:

```
def time_regexp_test(string)
    start = Time.now
    puts "parse start: #{start}"

    regexp_pattern = "[a-zA-Z0-9!#$%&'*+/=?^_`{|}~-]+(?:\.[a-zA-Z0-9!#$%&'*+/=?^_`{|}~-]+)*@(?:[a-zA-Z0-9](?:[a-zA-Z0-9-]*[a-zA-Z0-9])?\.)+[a-zA-Z0-9](?:[a-zA-Z0-9-]*[a-zA-Z0-9])?"

    email = string.scan(/#{regexp_pattern}/).flatten.last
    finish = Time.now
    puts "parse finish: #{finish}"
    puts "total #{(finish-start).to_s}"
    email
end

strings = [
'"Test test Real Estate - Test\'s International Real Estate" <test@test.com>',
'"Test test Real Estate - Christie\'s International Real Estate" <test@test.com>',
'"Test test Real Estate - Christie\'s International Real Estate"',
'"Test test Real Estate - Christie\'s International Real Estate" t@',
'"Test test Real Estate - testtesttest\'s International Real Estate" <test@test.com>',
'"testtesttest\'s" <test@test.com>',
'testtesttest\'s <test@test.com>'
]
strings.each_with_index do |string, n|
  puts "Test # #{n}"
  puts "Input: #{string}"
  time_regexp_test(string)
end
```

Result:

```
Test # 0
Input: "Test test Real Estate - Test's International Real Estate" <test@test.com>
parse start: 2018-04-19 17:43:26 +0200
parse finish: 2018-04-19 17:43:29 +0200
total 3.630606
Test # 1
Input: "Test test Real Estate - Christie's International Real Estate" <test@test.com>
parse start: 2018-04-19 17:43:29 +0200
parse finish: 2018-04-19 17:43:54 +0200
total 24.119056
Test # 2
Input: "Test test Real Estate - Christie's International Real Estate"
parse start: 2018-04-19 17:43:54 +0200
parse finish: 2018-04-19 17:43:54 +0200
total 0.000256
Test # 3
Input: "Test test Real Estate - Christie's International Real Estate" t@
parse start: 2018-04-19 17:43:54 +0200
parse finish: 2018-04-19 17:44:06 +0200
total 12.093272
Test # 4
Input: "Test test Real Estate - testtesttest's International Real Estate" <test@test.com>
parse start: 2018-04-19 17:44:06 +0200
parse finish: 2018-04-19 17:46:51 +0200
total 165.338206
Test # 5
Input: "testtesttest's" <test@test.com>
parse start: 2018-04-19 17:46:51 +0200
parse finish: 2018-04-19 17:46:51 +0200
total 0.000385
Test # 6
Input: testtesttest's <test@test.com>
parse start: 2018-04-19 17:46:51 +0200
parse finish: 2018-04-19 17:46:51 +0200
total 0.000369
```

We can see, that times of parsing some strings are incredibly huge (Test # 4).
Time is rising if we add some part of email address with @ character, and also rising if add characters to word with ' character.

Testing this regexp in https://regexr.com/3o721 - all working fast.

Where can be the problem?

**Update:**

Playing with deleting characters shows that delete of '-' character making parsing much faster ( 165.338206 -> 0.578216 ).

But Why?

```
string = '"Test test Real Estate - testtesttest\'s International Real Estate" <test@test.com>'
time_regexp_test(string.delete("-"))
parse start: 2018-04-19 18:17:21 +0200
parse finish: 2018-04-19 18:17:22 +0200
total 0.578216
```

Comment: scan was supposed to be improved in 2.5 -> https://github.com/ruby/ruby/commit/2b770b467455d7d7d6fa0c03ef177820a56b11f5

Comment: as I mentioned this tests are running on 2.5.1

Comment: yep - I saw that

Comment: You will be surprised but the only problem you have is single backslashes you used to escape the dots. Double each backslash. Or use a single quoted string literal, `regexp_pattern = '[a-zA-Z0-9!#$%&\'*+/=?^_\`{|}~-]+(?:\.[a-zA-Z0-9!#$%&\'*+/=?^_\`{|}~-]+)*@(?:[a-zA-Z0-9](?:[a-zA-Z0-9-]*[a-zA-Z0-9])?\.)+[a-zA-Z0-9](?:[a-zA-Z0-9-]*[a-zA-Z0-9])?'`

Comment: Or `regexp_pattern = /[a-zA-Z0-9!#\$%&'*+\/=?^_\`{|}~-]+(?:\.[a-zA-Z0-9!#\$%&'*+\/=?^_\`{|}~-]+)*@(?:[a-zA-Z0-9](?:[a-zA-Z0-9-]*[a-zA-Z0-9])?\.)+[a-zA-Z0-9](?:[a-zA-Z0-9-]*[a-zA-Z0-9])?/` and then `email = string.scan(regexp_pattern).flatten.last`

Comment: Thank's. So simple. @WiktorStribiżew may be you should put this as answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to properly escape the dot.

Either

```
regexp_pattern = '[a-zA-Z0-9!#$%&\'*+/=?^_`{|}~-]+(?:\.[a-zA-Z0-9!#$%&\'*+/=?^_`{|}~-]+)*@(?:[a-zA-Z0-9](?:[a-zA-Z0-9-]*[a-zA-Z0-9])?\.)+[a-zA-Z0-9](?:[a-zA-Z0-9-]*[a-zA-Z0-9])?'
email = string.scan(/#{regexp_pattern}/).flatten.last
```

Or

```
regexp_pattern = /[a-zA-Z0-9!#\$%&'*+\/=?^_`{|}~-]+(?:\.[a-zA-Z0-9!#\$%&'*+\/=?^_`{|}~-]+)*@(?:[a-zA-Z0-9](?:[a-zA-Z0-9-]*[a-zA-Z0-9])?\.)+[a-zA-Z0-9](?:[a-zA-Z0-9-]*[a-zA-Z0-9])?/
email = string.scan(regexp_pattern).flatten.last
```

Else, your `"\."` is parsed by the Ruby engine as a mere `.` that matches any character but a line break char by the Onigmo regex engine, and you get tripped up in the classical [catastrophic backtracking](https://www.regular-expressions.info/catastrophic.html).

If you want to reproduce the same behavior in the regex tester as you have in the Ruby code, just [remove a backslash before the dots in your pattern](https://regex101.com/r/8x8lmu/1).